# how can obtain this result writing a query as simple as I can

Tags: mysql

I have this row set:

```
ID player_id team_id       created
1      2        1    2011-05-03 19:07:03     
2      3        1    2011-05-05 12:13:18
3      2        5    2011-05-07 18:12:54
```

I would select player that belongs to team_id=1 but from this result i want to remove  player_id=2 cause this player actually has moved and he plays in team 5 (no more in team_id=1). So the final result will be:

```
ID player_id team_id       created
2      3        1    2011-05-05 12:13:18
```

How to write a query to do this? Can I write it in a single query? How?

Regards

Comment: *cause this player actually has moved and he plays in team 5* and it's not reflected in the DB? Maybe just select the player you want by ID.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think calling a `SELECT DISTINCT player_id, team_id` and ordering by created date would drop anything later than the last creation date.

Comment: I missed that as well at first - player 2 is in there twice, the newer created date shows the transfer

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can start by selecting everyone that has ever been a part of a team and then remove anyone who has an entry for another team that was created after their entry for the team in question. This query specifically allows you to change the `team_id` in only one place and have the correct result if you want to check more than one team.

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    my_table t1
WHERE
    t1.team_id = 1
AND
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT
            t2.id
        FROM
            my_table t2
        WHERE
            t2.player_id = t1.player_id
        AND
            t2.team_id != t1.team_id
        AND
            t2.created > t1.created);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit like:

```
SELECT allData.ID, allData.player_Id, allData.team_Id
FROM myTable allData
JOIN 
   (SELECT 
      player_id,  
      MAX(created) AS newestTime
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY player_id) mostRecent 
ON allData.player_id = mostRecent.player_id 
AND allData.created = mostRecent.newestTime
WHERE team_id = 1
```